# Best way to read many input files with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have many text files that we need to read in parallel. These are created with a Spark streaming job but that is a long story. Periodically need to do a batch calculation so we create a comma delimited list of files to pass in to sparkContext.textFile(fileList). The list can get very large (maybe 10000) and is all on hdfs.

The question is: what is the most performant way to read them?

Possibilities we thought of:

- Should we pass in the long list as we are doing now? This *seems* slow since the data  itself is not all that large.
- Should the list be broken up and read in groups appending the resulting RDDs?
- Should we move and append the text to get one dir with fewer large text files? This will be a bother since the data is separated into dirs with timestamps that we will need to keep around for other uses.

Comment: Have u got any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the files are in same directory and use sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(directoryPath) method to read all files in direcotory as JavaPairRDD where file name will be key and contents of file will be value.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two solutions that might suit your needs. In both of the methods, the variable `dir` must point to a directory available by all nodes on the cluster:

`wholeTextFiles(dir)` creates a single *PairRDD* object with a `key/value` structure, where `key` is the full path of a file and `value` is a string that contains *all* the content of that file. It creates an entry per file, and the partitioning is made depending upon how many executor cores there are available.

```
PairRDD (key,value):
hdfs://TextFile1.txt,this is the content of the file textfile4
hdfs://TextFile2.txt,this is the content of the file textfile4
hdfs://TextFile3.txt,this is the content of the file textfile4
hdfs://TextFile4.txt,this is the content of the file textfile4
```

`textFile(dir)`, instead, keeps the original structure and creates a partition per file, which can be useful for files that cannot be split into different partitions due to dependencies, for example. This means that having 1000 files willl cause 1000 partitions to be made.

Which method is best depends very much on the needs of your application. If the data is completely independent and the content of a file does not depend of itself, `wholeTextFiles` might be a better approach, while `textFile` might suit you if maintaining the file structure is important.

Comment: I know of these methods but the wholeTextFiles method does not fit and textFile is extremely slow. It actually has to scan through all file stats before deciding on partitioning. Reading a lot of small files is unusable with this method. If you copy all files into a single large file it is 10-100 times faster! Unfortunately Spark Streaming create a great number of small files.